# Why does my for loop only complete the task once?

Tags: java, file, loops

This method should call a method called "Add Book" until the file runs out of commmands. I've got 25 commands inside the file, but this code will only run the very first command. When I print out the array list it shows all 25 commands read in as strings. Any ideas?

Edit: I removed the semi colons and it still gives me this output.

file C:\Users\Remixt\workspace\2\test.csv

### Added ID001 Magee

### Address Book Content: [ID001 Magee]

```
        if (readerString.toUpperCase().startsWith("FILE")) {
        String tempString = readerString.substring(5);
        ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList <String>();
        String[] taskList = new String[300];
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(tempString));

            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                tempList.add(scanner.nextLine());

                }
            System.out.println(tempList);
            for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size();i++){
                taskList[i]= tempList.get(i);
                System.out.println(tempList.get(i));
                if(taskList[i].toUpperCase().contains("ADD"));{
                addBook(taskList[i]);
            } 
                if(tempList.get(i).toUpperCase().contains("REMOVE"));{
                delete(taskList[i]);
            }
            }
            }

         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("Cannot find Address file");
            start();
        }
    }
```

file C:\Users\Remixt\workspace\2\test.csv
[add,Magee, add,Back, add,Wailes, add,Laney, add,Atkinson, add,Finney, add,Stannbauer, add,Zapka, add,Yerke, add,Guillory, add,Detroye, add,Paulson, add,Knellinger, add,Christianson, add,Vogel, add,Nevers, add,Roth, add,Underwood, add,Ingersoll, add,Xavier, add,Trump, add,Queen, add,Olson, add,Hatfield, add,Echols, add,Jackson, print,, search,Christianson, search,Burke, remove,Hubbard, remove,Magee, remove,Wailes, remove,Laney, remove,Finney, remove,Stannbauer, remove,Zapka, remove,Yerke, remove,Guillory, remove,Detroye, remove,Paulson, remove,Knellinger, remove,Vogel, remove,Nevers, remove,Roth, remove,Underwood, remove,Ingersoll, remove,Xavier, remove,Trump, remove,Queen, remove,Olson, remove,Hatfield, remove,Echols, remove,Jackson, add,Back, print,, remove,Atkinson, remove,Back, remove,Christianson, add,Goodbye, print,]

### Added ID001 Magee

Address Book Content: [ID001 Magee]

Comment: Please show us the file content and the output you're getting.

Comment: I added it to the bottom.

Comment: Some thoughts: `String tempString = readerString.substring(5)` makes no sense to me, if your filename is `"test.csv"`. Second: your file content also makes no sense to me. Is this _one single_ line? Why isn't each `add` in his own line? How do you expect to read each `add` individually if you read the whole file (which is one line) with a `scanner.nextLine()` call. And please take more care in formatting your question. It is currently impossible to say what app output is and what the file content is. Also, why you're added *"Added ID001 Magee"* two times (in this quesiton)?

Answer (score 2):

An extra ; causing all the mess here.

That semicolon terminates the statement there ,And assuming it as a new block stating from there.

If you see closely

```
    if(taskList[i].toUpperCase().contains("ADD")); <----
```

and also here

```
 if(tempList.get(i).toUpperCase().contains("REMOVE"));<----
```

remove that colon and your if should look like

```
if(){

}
```

Comment: Well, I removed the semi colons and its still doing the same thing.